# Trying to load text with three.js returns several errors

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to display some text using `three.js`, but somehow I've been failing for the past hours.
My approach was to use `three-bmfont-text` to load text following [this tutorial](https://tympanus.net/codrops/2019/10/10/create-text-in-three-js-with-three-bmfont-text/) - I get the following errors:

> THREE.BufferAttribute: .setArray has been removed. Use BufferGeometry .setAttribute to replace/resize attribute buffers

and a few seconds later the app crashes returning this error:

> this.scene.add is not a function

Even though logging `this.scene` returns the correct scene.

**What's the correct approach here? Do I need to change my way of loading text?**

```
import * as THREE from 'three';

import fontFile from '../assets/fonts/RLUnno.fnt';
import fontAtlas from '../assets/fonts/RLUnno.png';

const MSDFShader = require('three-bmfont-text/shaders/msdf');
const createGeometry = require('three-bmfont-text');
const loadFont = require('load-bmfont');

export default class Title {
    constructor($el, $scene) {
        this.scene = $scene;
        this.title = $el;

        loadFont(fontFile, (err, font) => {

            const geometry = createGeometry({
                font: font,
                text: this.title.innerText
            });

            const loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
            loader.load(fontAtlas, (texture) => {
                this.init(geometry, texture);
            })
        });
    }

    init = (geometry, texture) => {
        const material = new THREE.RawShaderMaterial(MSDFShader({
            map: texture,
            color: 0x000000,
            side: THREE.DoubleSide,
            transparent: true,
            negate: false
        }));

        const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
        this.scene.add(mesh);
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using old version of ThreeJS, in the new version of ThreeJS - they have handled this error

See - https://github.com/Jam3/three-buffer-vertex-data/blob/master/index.js#L68 
(I assume you're using three-buffer-vertex-data library)

[image]

Alternatively you can get your library from this branch - https://github.com/ilidio/three-buffer-vertex-data

Comment: I'm using the latest npm version of three.js - but using `import * as THREE from 'three.js'` inside of the code I added above, returned an error for `three-bmfont-text`: "THREE is not defined". Adding `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/110/three.min.js` to index.html solved this issue, but might be the problem for my current error?